# Query xml with linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xsd

I am trying to query some informations from xml with linq but I am getting error like this - Yes I have defined - using System.Linq
Could you tell me, where is a problem? 
Thanks

> Error 1   Could not find an
>   implementation of the query pattern
>   for source type
>   'urn.P.IEEE.Item1671.Item2.Item2008.Item02.InstrumentDescription.InstrumentDescription'.
>   'Select' not found.   D:\Documents and
>   Settings\e539951\my documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  28  36  WindowsFormsApplication1

```
InstrumentDescription test = InstrumentDescription.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
 var query = from b in test
             select  new {  b.Identification };
```

Comment: Looks more like Query Object with linq, what is an `InstrumentDescription`, its not an `XDocument`?

Comment: is InstrumentDescription IQueryable?

Comment: InstrumentDescription is .cv file generated with linqtoxsd and then xsd to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `test` represents just the root element of the document, so you can't use LINQ on it – it's not an sequence.

What you should do depends on how your XSD looks like. For example, if there can be multiple `Identification` elements under the root `InstrumentDescription` element, then just accessing `test.Identitication` gives you the list.

Answer (score 0):

You're handling `InstrumentDescription` instead of an `XDocument` so it's probably that you need to make sure you `InstrumentDescription` class is IQueryable.

If you're actually wanting to do Linq against your XML, you either need to load it in as a dataset, or use Linq2XML (`using System.Xml.Linq`).

See more here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx